# Mouse hover only in the edges of a image?

Tags: html, css, hover

hi im want to make that the hover effect in css triggers only when the mouse its over the image and not starts when it over a div container of this image...

how can i do??

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <img class="encendido" src="foco_encendido.svg">
  <img class="apagado" src="foco_apagado.svg">
</div>

.apagado
{
  background: #333333;
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.contenedor
{
  width: 360px;
  height: 85%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.contenedor:hover img.apagado
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.encendido
{
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  bottom: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: then use :hover in img instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
.contenedor:hover img.apagado
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.apagado:hover
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answerd i tried that but its worst because every time the mouse moves the image flash.. like the efect its turn on and off... and the only way that stops its putting the other way.

but my problem is not that  i just want that the hover efect runs in the edge of the image not in the edge of the div that contains that image